# rewrite rule no trailing slash?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a link setup : http://website.com/link - the problem is when clicked it goes to http://website.com/link/ - also when I type in the url http://website.com/link the redirect goes to http://website.com/link/

So how could I make it that if http://website.com/link is entered then the url does not go to http://website.com/link/

Comment: Please, put your rewrite rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase your.domain
# Rewrite an address with optional trailing slash to one without it
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ $1 [L]
```

try this out

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, sorry, deleted firefox history and now it does not make the redirect anymore